# ffmpeg, live MPEG-TS demux & decode

Tags: c++, linux, ffmpeg

### Environment

- Ubuntu-14
- C++
- ffmpeg

### Use-case

- Live SPTS is received via UDP by a 3rd party module
- TS Packets are received iteratively
- The TS Video (ES) should be decoded in minimal latency

### Considered Implementation

- Upon TS packet reception, immediately push it to the TS demux
- Once enough packets are received the video format is resolvable, create the video codec
- Push each video packet into the video decoder
- Once enough video packets were processed the video codec result a valid output frame

### Problem at-hand

Can this be done w/ ffmpeg?!?!, … using “avformat_open_input” mandate a file to read from… I need a way where I can iteratively push packets to the TS demuxer ( w/ minimal latency )…

### Does ffmpeg support the above mentioned use-case? How?